# Make [arch] a synonym of [arch-linux]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-request

The tag [arch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/arch) has 14 questions compared to [arch-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux)'s 209 questions. We could manually retag those few questions.

But Arch is a popular shortcut for Arch Linux and it is possible that this would appear later. It would be more appropriate to deal with this now instead of doing it again and again.

So in short, make [arch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/arch) a synonym of [arch-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done, thanks for bringing this up!

```
updating post history, 16 rows affected
updating posts, 16 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 13 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [arch-linux] and [arch] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
5 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
```